# Git for my Remote Server for an Android Application

Tags: android, eclipse, git, workflow, linode

I'm running a remote Linode server - Debian 7.5 Profile (Latest 64 bit (3.16.5-x86_64-linode46))

A co-worker of mine already has an android application project locally on their machine.

I want to be able to transfer that project onto my server and adapt the git technology to it. So that it will enable me and the colleague to simultaneously work on the project.

How can I achieve this?

Are there any step by step tutorials on how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read this for using git on the server.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server

Tip. If you guys can use a shared folder (e.g., samba shared folder), just keep the common git repository there. Then you guys can clone it and push commits into the git not shared folder.

```
$ git clone samba_shared_folder_path
```

You can understand why it works after reading the above link.

Tip2, You can try the following at you local. (Just forget about 4-digit number)

a. make a local git repo and a commit

```
 2037  mkdir common
 2038  cd common/
 2039  git init
 2040  touch sample.txt
 2041  git add sample.txt 
 2043  git commit -m "testing"
```

b. clone the commit.git into another folder

```
 2044  cd ..
 2045  git clone common my_common
 2046  cd my_common/
 2047  echo "new line" >> sample.txt 
 2048  git add sample.txt 
 2049  git commit -m "new commit from my_common"
```

c. push new commit from my_common(local) into common(remote)

```
 2052  git push ../common HEAD:from_new_common
```

Just think about using a shared folder instead of `common` folder at your local.

Comment: so you're saying thats all i need to do that command? I want to be able to upload the app files directory to my server, update it via concurrent changes from me and my colleague. Then commit changes to the original directory.

Comment: Once set the git folder under shared folder, you guys can use the git folder as a common source code repository.

Comment: @Chris Hey, I have updated my answer. Just read it and read the link I mentioned. :)

Comment: it's just not sitting well with me, where is the push to the server?

Comment: What if the folder, common is the shared folder? I used this sometimes. I recommend you read the link I mentioned.